XMLwriter requeriments
in Genexus 9 we are using XMLwriter class and we need to know what is the requeriments to install in the client pc, maybe any dll?
We need to run xmlwriter class in the client pc and we are reinstalling application.  What we need to install package?

Please, be more specific... Genexus 9 using which generator? Reinstalling which application?
